# Does ruby support ranges in case statement?

Tags: ruby

I want to do this:

```
case cost

    when cost between 1 and 3 then cost * 1.1
    when cost between 3 and 5 then cost * 1.2
else
    0
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, since `Range#===` is defined to be the same as `include?`, you can use ranges in `case` statements:

```
case cost
when 1..3 then cost * 1.1
when 3..5 then cost * 1.2
```

Comment: @Blankman Ranges can be used; 0.01..0.99 is a range; so yes, it will work.  You should be writing (and reading) code; both of your questions--really just a variation of the same--will answer themselves when you start writing!  (This is meant to be encouraging, not disparaging.)

Comment: @sepp2k what would happen in this case if the cost was equal to 3? Would it evaluate as the first or second scenario?

Comment: @Andrew The first. Ranges are inclusive in both operands when using `..` (and exclusive in the right operand when using `...`) and `case` takes the first pattern that matches.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  I don't know why you didn't think to Google this or just try it (which is the beauty of Ruby, IMO: things usually work the way you think they should), but I'll answer just the same: http://ilikestuffblog.com/2008/04/15/how-to-write-case-switch-statements-in-ruby/

Specifically:

```
case expression
when min..max
   statements
else
   statements
end
```

Comment: Alas, your answer is now what comes up when Googling this. The success of SO, I suppose.